# How does matlab function imwrite() scale the data while writing the output

Tags: file, matlab, io

I am using matlab for some image processing. So in this context,
I have a question about the Matlab/Octave imwrite() function.

When I call imwrite as:

```
imwrite(img,'file.bmp');
```

where img is data of class/type double in Matlab and has negative values as well as positive values.

How does Matlab imwrite()  function scale this data to write a BMP image which would have values between [0,255]. I could not understand the code of imwrite.m

What type of scaling/range adjustment does it do, Is it:-

1]

```
img = img - min(min(img));  

img = img .* ((255)/max(max(img)));
```

or any other type of scaling.

Thank you.

-AD.

Comment: Not an answer, but a suggestion. Why dont you do the conversion yourself and supply imwrite with uint8s?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are writing the 2D matrix. This matrix will be written as indexed image. If no colormap provided, the image will be grayscale.

If the matrix `img` is of `uint8` class, IMWRITE writes the actual values to the image file.

If the matrix is `double`, IMWRITE assumes all values are between 0 and 1. All negative values will be truncated to 0 and all larger than 1 values will be 1. Then they scaled by 255 and converted to uint8.

See [Class Support](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/imwrite.html#brudiy4-1) in [IMWRITE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/imwrite.html) documentation.

**EDIT**

Here is how you can reproduce the conversion:

```
img = (rand(10)-0.5)*3;
imwrite(img,'test.bmp');
IMG = imread('test.bmp');

img2 = img;
img2(img2<0)=0;
img2(img2>1)=1;
img2 = uint8(img2*255);

%# compare imwrite vs. manual conversion
isequal(IMG,img2)

ans =

     1
```